# Using ParseKit Tokenization and DelimitedString

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, parsekit

I'm trying to use [ParseKit's](http://parsekit.com/) [Tokenization](http://parsekit.com/tokenization.html) with SQL Server syntax. If you take a look at the following example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
  @MyId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN
  -- something something
END
GO
```

I'm using the following to setup comments (and multiline comments):

```
PKTokenizer *t = [PKTokenizer tokenizerWithString: [inputString substringWithRange: range]];

// SQL does not support // comments.
[t.commentState removeSingleLineStartMarker: @"//"];

// But it does support -- comments.
[t setTokenizerState:t.commentState from: '-' to:'-'];
[t.commentState addSingleLineStartMarker: @"--"];

[t setTokenizerState: t.commentState from: '/' to: '/'];
[t.commentState addMultiLineStartMarker: @"/*" endMarker: @"*/"];
```

Which sets up support for handling sql comments. Now I'm trying to add support for detecting parameters such as `@MyId`. Current the tokenizer picks these up as words, but does not include the `@` in the string value. My thought was to attempt using a `delimitState` by doing:

```
[t.delimitState addStartMarker: @"@" endMarker: @" " allowedCharacterSet: [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
```

Then check for `token.isDelimitedString`, but it does not seem to pick any up.

Am I going about this wrong? Any suggestions on how I could include the `@` in my wordstate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

To match `@MyId` as a single delimited string token, try:

```
[t setTokenizerState:t.delimitState from:'@' to:'@'];
[t.delimitState addStartMarker:@"@" endMarker:nil allowedCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked like a charm! Thanks for the great component.